Why does cell potential decrease as reaction proceeds forward in a voltaic cell( Without any Math)
What is the conceptual reason why should cell potential decrease as a spontaneous cell reaction proceeds in the forward direction?

For plain text formatting by StackExchange markdown, see as inspiration SE meta - formatting // SE meta -  tables  // Less known formatting tips

Four formatting guides for chemical/mathematical formulas/expressions/equations: Basics // Detailed // Upright vs Italics // Math SE Mathjax tutorial
// Not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

It is unclear what resources you have consulted before asking this question and what conclusion you have made from that. //
Searching domains stackexchange.com, wikipedia.org and optionally libretexts.org is assumed as prerequisite before asking. // Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Sorry, but you can't do the science properly without any maths, you can't just decide to opt out of it

"without any math" is quite the crutch you've put on yourself, considering this has to do with the kinetics of the redox reaction. See: Nernst equation.

I've Learnt about the Nernst Equation and it is what predicts that the emf should decrease but a logical explanation was what I was looking for...

If you multiply the N. equation by nF  (the old good energy =voltage x charge),  you get   the equation relating activity and chemical potential that is the partial derivative of Gibbs energy per molar amount. And the change of Gibbs energy of the cell.is the top hard limit of work that could be done by such a change. The cell voltage is then proportionality constant between passed charge and work done.

As an analogy, imagine two vessels filled with water with different levels, connected by a tube with a small turbine.

The water flow is like the cell electric current.
The water level difference, and the equivalent pressure difference, is like the cell voltage/potential.
The multiple of water level difference and water flow/passed water volume is proportional to maximal mechanical power/work.
The multiple of the cell voltage and electrical current/charge is proportional to maximal galvanic power/work.
When more and more of water (charge) passes, the water level difference (cell voltage) decreases and the same passed water volume (charge) can do less and less work.
At the end, the level difference and voltage is zero and water/the cell cannot do any more work.

Generally, the closer is a system to its thermodynamic equilibrium by undergoing spontaneous change, the less effective it is in doing work. That is reflected in decreasing of cell voltage while a cell is being discharged.
More details require math.

So you say the cell potential should decrease as more work is done by the cell, as is also predicted by the Nernst Equation , but why would say in a zinc/Copper cell the higher potential of copper half cell decrease as electrons are being transferred to it? If we assume that rate of its dissolution stays constant then is it that rate of it being deposited changes?

Please add math if the above can be explained by it...

Here is a qualitative explanation, without any math. In the beginning, a galvanic cell is built with two half-cells having different reduction potentials. A spontaneous chemical reaction occurs and goes on producing a measurable voltage between the electrodes. After a certain time, the reaction slows down. The voltage goes down, too. At the end, the sysem goes to equilibrium. The reaction rate goes down to zero. At this point the voltage between the electrodes is also zero. No reaction -> no voltage.
